# Javascript array to php with post

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have the following in my js script :

```
    cats = []; cats.push(cat1); cats.push(cat2);
    $.post( URL+"/edit-article.php", { id: artId, title: "PZujF0 wxKLCW", content: "ILEn3o oU9Ft6oU5", author: author, cat_id: cats } ).done(function( data2 ) {......}
```

cat1 and cat2 are some random generated integers, so i send to my php script an array of integers. How do i retrieve them inside my php script ? Currently i have something like this:

```
$cat_id=array();
$cat_id=array_map('intval',explode(',',$_POST['cat_id']));
```

but my code assumes that the sent array from js is the equivalent of the following :

```
<form action='edit-article.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='cat_id' value='1,2'>
</form>
```

From the code i posted in js it's obvious that there are only 2 integers so i could probably make something like :

```
$cat_id=$_POST['cat_id'];
$id1=(int)$cat_id[0];
$id2=(int)$cat_id[1];
```

But how can i correctly parse the array in PHP for any number of elements and make sure i am left with an array of ints ?

LE: The problem i have is understanding how JS sends the data to my php script, in order to correctly extract the data. As i gather, $POST values are always retrieved as strings(is it valid for values sent from JS or just forms and stuff?), but is my cat_id array an array of strings like {'1','2','3'} or is it a string like '1,2,3' ?

Comment: use a for loop to get all the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're sending an array, so there's no need to explode:

```
$cat_id = array_map('intval', $_POST['cat_id']);
```

Alternatively, you can create the comma separated list on the JavaScript side:

```
cats = cats.join();
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i wasn't so sure of, if i needed the explode or not, thank you :)